# Creating An Email Authentication With Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I'm a beginner programmer and am working on an email confirmation. Once users have registered it sends them to a page to enter a confirmation code, which will be sent to the email they used. If submitted correctly it saves the User and logs them in.

I had looked into using Devise and maybe that's the way to go, but it seems I would spend as much time learning someone else's code when I could learn to do it myself. My repo is [Here](https://github.com/latinforadapt/grmbly_app).

What I was thinking of coding (in my User controller) is shaping up like this...what do you think? Am I completely off and would be better figuring out Devise/Authlogic or am I on the right track? I'm using rails 3.1. Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

```
def   confirmation_code_to_register(string)
  @confirmation_code = #random number
end

def create_start
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  #send email with @confirmation_code via ActionMailer
  redirect_to page_to_enter_confirmation_code
  email_authenticate
end


def email_authenticate
  if #confirmation code user enters == @confirmation_code
    create_finish
  else
    #sorry, you entered the wrong confirmation code. 
  end
end

def create_finish
  if @user.save
    sign_in @user
    flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Site"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    @title = "Sign Up"
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using Sorcery instead of Devise. There is Railscast about it.

https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery

It more simpler to use, and I think it fulfill your authentication needs.

PD: Check the Edit I did to your post. Try to use that syntax when you post code (just indent the code, no html markup)

EDIT:

And that code should be in the User model, not the controller. Try to keep your controller small, very small. Put all the logic you can in the models.

Comment: Thanks for helping with the markup. Perhaps I should move the method: confirmation_code_to_register(string) to the User model, but shouldn't the others stay in the User controller? Also, if possible I want to stay away from sorcery, devise, etc because I view this as a great learning opportunity .... what do you think?

Comment: Yes, just confirmation_code_to_register(string) to the model. Authorization is a field where a lot of things can go wrong, so it is usually a good idea to use something like Sorcery or Devise. But if you want to cook your own, go ahead :) But maybe it would be easier for you if you familiarize yourself with one authorization solution, so you get to grasp what you would need to implement in the case you wanted to create your own solution.

Comment: +1 for using a tested solution like Sorcery or Devise. Security is definitely one thing you don't want to DIY if you can avoid it. As a bonus those projects are open source so you can see what they do and how they do it.